# WordNet(JWI MIT) : How to find words with a particular alphabet/phrase?

Tags: dictionary, words, wordnet, vocabulary, jwi

How can I find the list of words starting with a particular alphabet or particular phrase using JWI MIT interface(http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/) from WordNet API(http://wordnet.princeton.edu/). Any Idea, how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution or any work-around?

Comment: No, right now, this app of mine is pending. Not working on it.

Comment: Ok! I just implemented JWI in my swing app. I don't think JWI provide anything to perform a search for words using a phrase/fragement. all you can do is let the user enter a word, then your program search for its meaning in wordnet and if meaning was found, show it to user else display a message to user that requested word was not found.! because I have been searching for a solution on how to perform search in wordnet using JWI, for like 16 Hours now, all I found is a few posts with no replies.

Answer (score 2):

JWI does not provide anything like this but you can always use [Full Text Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search) techniques to achieve this kind of functionality. There are many libraries providing indexing and text searching functionality.

I have personally used [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) and [SqlLite](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) in Dot.Net C# for indexing and full text search but you can also use them in java and other programming languages.

[An Introduction to Apache Lucene for Full-Text Search](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/introduction-to-apache-lucene-for-full.html)

[Full Text Search in SqlLite](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)